# How do I use telescopic cancellation to prove the Fibonacci Sum Identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I am reading a textbook which attempts to prove the Fibonacci Sum Identity by rearranging the Fibonacci recurrence relation as follows and then using telescoping cancellation to prove the identity:

$$F(n) = F(n+2) - F(n+1),\space\text{where}\space (n = 0, 1, 2, ....)$$

$$F(0) = F(2) - F(1)$$
$$F(1) = F(3) - F(2)$$
$$F(2) = F(4) - F(3)$$
$$...$$
$$F(n) = F(n+2) - F(n+1)$$

If we add the left hand side then we have

$$F(0) + F(1) + F(2) +...+F(n)$$

And on the right hand side all the terms cancel except $F(n+2)$ and $-F(1)$.

The book does not explain how or why all the terms except F(n+2) and -F(1) on the right hand side cancel out. As far as i can tell, after cancellation, the right hand side is

-F(1) +F(4) -F(n+2) -F(n+1)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Take a particular $n$, such as $n=7$, and write down **all** the differences, not just the four mentioned explicitly, and you will see the massive cancellation.

Comment: If you got $F(n+2)-F(n+1)+F(4)-F(1)$ on the right, then you only got $F(0)+F(1)+F(2)+F(n)$ on the left. IOW the three dots are missing. Cure? Follow André's advice. If you want to be rigorous about it, then this is a case of "the $\ldots$ are a shorthand for a proof by full-blown induction". Going through the steps of an induction won't shed more light to the validity of the equation here.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you are looking for $F(j)$ where $2 \le j \le n$.  This appears on the left hand side in $$F(j)=F(j+2)-F(j+1)$$ and on the right-hand side in $$F(j-2)=F(j)-F(j-1)$$ $$F(j-1)=F(j+1)-F(j)$$ so when you do the sum, $F(j)$ appears in the sum on the left, but cancels on the right.

Meanwhile

- $F(0)$ appears in $F(0)=F(2)-F(1)$ so is only in the sum on the left;
- $F(1)$ appears in $F(1)=F(3)-F(2)$ and $F(0)=F(2)-F(1)$ so is positive in the sum on the left and negative in the sum on the right the right
- $F(n+1)$ appears in $F(n-1)=F(n+1)-F(n)$ and $F(n)=F(n+2)-F(n-1)$ so does not appear in the sum on the left and cancels in the sum on the right
- $F(n+2)$ appears in  $F(n)=F(n+2)-F(n-1)$ so is only in the sum on the right

So by looking at which terms remain in the sum, you get $$F(0) + F(1) + F(2) +\cdots +F(n) = F(n+2)-F(1)$$